# Drupal 7 PDOException

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7

I've made a script that imports stuff from one database and puts it into another; the problem is that it breaks with the message:

> PDOException: in hcap_import_do() (line 215 of /mnt/hgfs/docroot/hcapdrupal/site_drupal/public_html/sites/all/modules/custom/hcap/hcap.module).

The code that the following one:

```
db_insert('hcap_candidates')->fields(array(
  'id' => $e['old_id'],
  'pic' => $e['logo'],
  'placed' => $e['placed'],
  'title' => $e['title'],
  'name' => $e['name'],
  'interim' => $e['interim'],
  'permanent' => $e['permanent'],
  'birth' => $e['birth'],
  'marital_status' => $e['marital'],
  'adress' => $e['address'],
  'city' => $e['city'],
  'postal' => $e['postal'],
  'phone_home' => $e['phone_home'],
  'phone_work' => $e['phone_work'],
  'phone_mobile' => $e['phone_mobile'],
  'email1' => $e['email1'],
  'email2' => $e['email2'],
  'reg_by' => $e['reg_by'],
  'cand_head' => $e['cand_head'],
  'cand_body' => $e['cand_body'],
  'prominent' => $e['prominent'],
  'broadcast' => $e['broadcast'],
  'cv' => $e['cv'],
  'old_id' => $e['old_id']
))->execute();  // This is line 215.
```

Does anyone have any clue as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a "try ... catch" block to learn more about the error. I'd need more surrounding code and the table structure to understand why the query is failing, but the syntax appears to be correct.

In case you aren't sure, here is what a "try ... catch" block looks like in PHP:

```
<?php
try {
db_insert('hcap_candidates')
  ->fields(
    array(
      'id' => $e['old_id'],
      'pic' => $e['logo'],
      'placed' => $e['placed'],
      'title' => $e['title'],
      'name' => $e['name'],
      'interim' => $e['interim'],
      'permanent' => $e['permanent'],
      'birth' => $e['birth'],
      'marital_status' => $e['marital'],
      'adress' => $e['address'],
      'city' => $e['city'],
      'postal' => $e['postal'],
      'phone_home' => $e['phone_home'],
      'phone_work' => $e['phone_work'],
      'phone_mobile' => $e['phone_mobile'],
      'email1' => $e['email1'],
      'email2' => $e['email2'],
      'reg_by' => $e['reg_by'],
      'cand_head' => $e['cand_head'],
      'cand_body' => $e['cand_body'],
      'prominent' => $e['prominent'],
      'broadcast' => $e['broadcast'],
      'cv' => $e['cv'],
      'old_id' => $e['old_id'],
    )
  )
  ->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  print_r($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

There is probably a simple issue with your query (no table called `hcap_candidates`, no field in that table called `marital_status`, etc.). The exception message should tell you all you need to know.

BTW, print_r is only one quick-and-dirty way to see the output in a browser. You can also use [watchdog](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog), [drupal_set_message](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message)...

Comment: the try method actually generated an SQLSTATE error, which is exactly what i wanted. thanks alot!

Comment: try catch is a great idea for solving drupal errors... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the problem exactly but make sure that you implemented the following steps

1- you defined the 2 databases in your settings.php file

2- you use db_set_active("database2name"); before you insert your data to the {database2name}